# How to deal with 404 error in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I write the controller, routing, or view to present 404s when a routing error occurs?

For example,if the user access a url address

`http://0.0.0.0:3000/posts/likes`

The `likes` path isn't a method in the routing. How do I redirect it to 404 page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.In the **application_controller.rb**

```
# ..
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :record_not_found

private
def record_not_found(e)
  render ‘errors/not_found’, :status => 404
end
```

2.Create a **errors** folder and a file named **not_found.html.erb**

3.Add the source to **application_controller.rb**

```
def record_not_found(e)
  render ‘errors/not_found’, :status => 404, :layout => ‘error’
end
```

Answer (score 3):

A quick googling gave few resources. I would suggest following two.

- https://github.com/Sharagoz/rails_exception_handler
- http://ramblinglabs.com/blog/2012/01/rails-3-1-adding-custom-404-and-500-error-pages

Though I didnt use any of these personally, I think the gem can help you robustly.
And yes, second link came from a real life scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Rails allows you to define your own "exceptions app" to handle errors. This is one way to handle errors. In `application.rb`:

```
config.exceptions_app = self.routes
```

And then in your routes:

```
match '/404', to: 'errors#not_found'
match '/500', to: 'errors#error'
```

Then you just need an `ErrorsController` with methods for different errors you want to handle, and template files for each one, plus an `errors.html.erb` layout file if you want to use it.

`ActionController::RoutingError` and `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` automatically raise a 404 in production.